Thunder Client didn't show the value query parameter
I am using Thunder Client for testing code
It works fine for full URL  http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users

But when trying it, with query parameter it does not give the result, it shows an error
GET:    {URL}/users
Query Parameters
URL:    http://localhost:4000/api/v1/

I try to use it in various formats but the result is the same. Is it a problem with my query parameter settings?

Try: https://i.sstatic.net/Dd7VCSg4.png (or make clear why that is not an option in you case ...)

Please note that in your screenshort {URL} ends with a / and after that you added /users, should that not be users ???

Checking your solutions

Please post your comments as a solution

It's a private route, I added the token, but it expired. Then I extende the token expiration time from code then its works fine.
Here is the solution


Here is the token expiration code
jwt.sign(payload, 'secret-key', { expiresIn: '10m' });

